# Multiple simultaneous SaveChangesAsync() with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a question guys, what would happen if I (using Entity Framework) call SaveChangesAsync() multiple times simultaneously? What would happen when more than one thread is trying to actually write data in the database at the same time? How is it handled? I'm working a project where I have to fetch-and-save periodically and I'm afraid that the time it takes to process each package of data in some cases might be bigger than the time-interval between calls. I'm new to Entity Framework and I find it fascinating, but I still have my doubts regarding the action behind the scenes. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Then *don't* use "fetch-and-save". What you describe is an UPDATE. What's the point of *loading* an object if you only want to update some values?

Comment: EF `DbContext` and related are **not** thread-safe. I think this should answer your question.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you all for the comments. Panagiotis I think you misunderstood my question, it's not an update, I'm dealing with new data all the time, it's more like fetch-and-store. I'll be calling a service to provide me with new data all the time, data that I have to store in a database. @Ivan I got the idea but what if I create a new DbContext in each thread? Would EF will queue the insert commands or will give me some sort of locking exception?

Answer (score 1):

If "simultaneously" meand by multiple threads then you can't do that because EF is not thread safe.

Here are some examples that might help you.

https://github.com/mjrousos/MultiThreadedEFCoreSample

Reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/core/miscellaneous/async

Comment: It's not said that one context is used in multiple threads, only that multiple `SaveChangesAsync()` calls are executed "simultaneously". The question is far too broad and vague to answer.

Comment: I've added that as a precision